# Ruby on Rails: How to display previous values in select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

this is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm new to Ruby on Rails, so I'm really sorry if I'm asking the question wrong.

My problem: I have two classes (word and category) and now I try to assign several categories to one word over the variable `syntactical_category`, for that I use a select_tag. This works nicely, when the user creates a new word as you can see in this snippet from the command line:

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"EwGk/QrOma4JGJhSBjAT6fW9BqvuCJCEPYgNC9i/okOuQZBbh1ArNEfvuHvDRwY0Q2tABYTc/b3n3tAIlQmJRg==", 
  "word"=>{
    "name_de"=>"This is a test", 
    "description_de"=>"Test Description", 
    "syntactical_category"=>"5721e7fa8cc4b3285c000004", 
    "semantical_categories_ids"=>["57921a358cc4b36e42000001"]
  }, 
  "locale"=>"de"
}
```

But when the user tries to edit a word afterwards, the select_tag ignores the value(s) from the database and only displays the first category of all potential categories and overwrites the old value(s) if the user submits the word again. This is not what i want.

Does anybody have a solution for this problem?
I'm using Ruby 2.2.3, RubyonRails 4.2.4 and MongoDB 3.0.9, Mongoid and haml if this information helps you.

Please find below my code.

#### word.rb

```
class Word
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
  include MultiLanguageText

  belongs_to :syntactical_category, class_name: "Category", inverse_of: nil, :autosave => true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :semantical_categories, class_name: "Category", inverse_of: nil, :autosave => true
  field :name_de, type: String
  field :name_en, type: String
  field :description_de, type: String
  field :description_en, type: String
end
```

#### words_controller.rb

```
class WordsController < ApplicationController
  helper MultiLanguageText

  def index
    @word = Word.all
  end

  def show
    @word = Word.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @word = Word.new
  end

  def create
    @word = Word.new(word_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @word.save
        format.html { redirect_to @word, notice: t("word_create_success") }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @word }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @word.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @word = Word.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @word = Word.find params[:id]
    @word.update_attributes(word_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @word.update(word_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @word, notice: t("word_update_success") }
        format.json { render :index, status: :ok, location: @word }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @word = Word.find(params[:id])
    @word.destroy
    flash[:notice] = t(:delete_confirmation)
    redirect_to words_path
  end

  def word_params
    allow = [:name_de, :name_en, :description_de, :description_en, :syntactical_category, {:semantical_categories_ids => []}]
    params.require(:word).permit(allow)
  end
end
```

#### words/_form.html.haml

```
= form_for @word do |w|
  .field
    .input-append
      = select_tag 'word[semantical_categories_ids][]', options_for_select(Category.where(category_type: 'semantic').where(:name_de.exists => true).collect{|c| [c.name_de, c.id]})
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution for my problem. I'm not sure if this is "the way to do it" but for me it works fine.

```
  - @word['semantical_categories_ids'] = [''] if !@word['semantical_categories_ids'].is_a? Array
  - @word['semantical_categories_ids'].each do |entry|
    = select_tag 'word[semantical_categories_ids][]', options_for_select(Category.where(category_type: 'semantic').where(:name_de.exists => true).collect{|c| [c.name_de, c.id]}, entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `@word.semantical_categories_ids` after the collection

```
= select_tag 'word[semantical_categories_ids][]', options_for_select(Category.where(category_type: 'semantic').where(:name_de.exists => true).collect{|c| [c.name_de, c.id]}, @word.semantical_categories_ids)
```

and I think it should accept multiple values. If yes add `multiple: true` at the end

Comment: Hi deepak, thank you for your answer but now I get the following error, when I load the page: `undefined method semantical_categories_ids' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f6388e0fea0>`

Comment: now i have the the following error `undefined method semantical_categories_ids for #<Word:0x00000002890420>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `multiple` selection `select_tag`
So, you have to do below

`= select_tag 'word[semantical_categories_ids][]', options_for_select(YOUR_COLLECTION,ARRAY_OF_SELECTED_VALUES),{multiple: true}`

Note: Add `,{multiple: true}` to your `select_tag`

Comment: Hi hitesh, thank you for your solution. This do not work for me, I get the following error `undefined method semantical_categories_ids for #<Word:0x000000028992c8>`.
Are you sure that i should use words instead of word?
I tried it both ways but get the same error.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that, i tried this as well.

Comment: Are you sure that i should use words instead of word?, Sorry it's typo use `word`

Comment: my code at the moment is:
= select_tag 'word[semantical_categories_ids][]', options_for_select(Category.where(category_type: 'semantic').where(:name_de.exists => true).collect{|c| [c.name_de, c.id]}, @word.semantical_categories_ids),{multiple: true}`
and the output is `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method semantical_categories_ids for #<Word:0x000000057828a0>):`

Comment: Will you please provide the output of `@word.semantical_categories`?